# Sound Devices 633 or Sony PCM-D100

Tags: sound-devices, sony, devices

These are very different devices that ultimately do the same thing. 
I am a documentary photographer/film maker and I also have a hobby of making field recordings.

I currently have a Roland R-26 previously a PCM-D50. The R26 offers me 6 channels and two XLR's.

My current line of thinking is that the D100 is insanely high quality for inbuilt mics, and I could also use my Lav with it. And the 633 is almost everything that the D100 is but requires external mics and a larger bag. 
being a photographer means having a bag with cameras and lenses batteries etc, adding a D100 to that is nothing, but adding a 633 to that is additional batteries, mics, cables etc..

Im just not entirely sure which direction to go.

Lets not talk about the cost factor because we all know how much these things cost and the difference between the two items.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't feel the need to use your condenser mics, purchase the PCM-D100.
As a PCM-D100 owner I can tell you that its internal mics are head and shoulders above those of the D50 and its preamps are fantastic for use with even low-output dynamic microphones. Simply put, it has the quietest preamps you can get along with a -$1000 recorder on the market. However, it's impossible to use it with condenser microphones as the PCM-D100 doesn't provide phantom power.
IMO, the SD633 is a little overkill for what you're goind to achieve -- especially considering the fact that you already have a 6-channel recorder which can provide phantom power for condenser mics if needed. So my vote would be the PCM-D100.
HTH.

Comment: hi amir, can you expand on the comparison between the D50 and D100? is it the mic's or the conversion that makes the difference?